# How to open an external program in java

Tags: java, windows

I'm looking to create a desktop helper program with Java, a couple `JOptionPane` option dialogues, and in that I would like to open programs (both internal and external, internal being something like notepad, external being a game like league of legends, something that doesn't come with Windows if that makes any sense whatsoever) I also want to open webpages, but I've got that worked out with this code:

```
try {
    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.gamestop.com/wii-u/games/super-smash-bros/114504"));
    giftinfo();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there a way to open other (non Java) programs from a Java program?

Comment: Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);

Comment: Failed to work... wouldnt accept a file name as a string or as a param

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");`

Comment: @SAXTEN2011 its a File class. `File file = new File (String path);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is short, yes you can open every inbuilt application has a command that it can be ran from run command window. Here is an example for opening notepad.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Notepad Opening");
        Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = runTime.exec("notepad");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Notepad Closing");
        process.destroy();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```